# Loop number of times as per row value

Tags: python, pandas

My cust_valid Csv file looks like below

```
Territory  NoOfCustomer
D00060     10
D00061     20
D00065     70
D00067     90
```

I have to create a Unique Id based on Number of NoOfCustomer like If NoOfCustomer <=50
then I have to create 10 different Unique ID for Territory D00060 and 10 different Unique ID for Territory D00061.

Here I read my csv file in pandas like

```
csv_file = 'cust_valid.csv'
df=pd.read_csv(csv_file,delimiter="|")
```

Filtered having customers <= 50

```
low_dense = df['NoOfCustomer'] <=50
```

And then iterted low_dense like

```
for idx, item in df[low_dense].iterrows():
    ???
```

And I stuck in nested looping here.Do I need to do an nested looping or it can be done any other ways.

My Output will look like

```
Territory   NoOfCustomers    UniqueID
D00060       10              0001AB9BHBHB
D00060       10              0001AB8HHJJL
D00060       10              0001AB7JHJHJ
D00060       10              0001AB9EWGHJ
D00060       10              0001AB0JIJKJ
```

Comment: Notice that `low_dense` is a boolean mask array. I think you want this instead: `low_dense = df[df['NoOfCustomer'] <=50]`.

Answer (score 0):

<del>The question is a bit unclear of how you want to store those ids, but</del>  if you want them in the same row you can do it like this:

```
def f(x):
    return [str(uuid.uuid4()) for i in range(10)]

df = pd.DataFrame({"Territory": ['D60','D61','D65'], 'NoC': [10,20,70] })

df["Ids"] = df[df['NoC'] <=50].apply(f,axis =1)
```

This adds a column with an array of 10 ids on the rows with <= 50 customers.

(After edited output in question).  You can continue like this:

```
df = pd.merge(df[['NoC','Territory']],df['Ids'].str.split(',',expand=True),left_index=True,right_index=True)
df = pd.melt(df,id_vars = ['NoC','Territory']).sort_values(['Territory','variable'])
```

Which would give one row with a unique id.

Comment: I have added what you need @PradeepKumar